# for loop, leaving start value blank?

Tags: c, for-loop, styles

I'm writing a for loop for a variable `start` whose value has already been calculated elsewhere in the program.

Doing `for(start; start<end; start++)` gives a warning, and

`for(start=start; start<end; start++)` seems like an unnecessary assignment.

The other option I can think of would be the following--is this okay, or would you classify it as poor coding style?

```
for(; start<end; start++){
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Just leave it empty. or use a different variable as in `for(i=start; i < end; i++){...}`

Answer (score 5):

That's not poor coding style IMHO, but perhaps you want to use a `while` instead?

```
while (start < end)
{
  //do stuff
  ++start;
}
```

It's just a matter of taste, really.

Answer (score 3):

Leaving any part of the `for` loop out is OK. Leaving all parts out is OK too - in fact, it's the idiomatic way of expressing an infinite loop as shown in the [K&R book.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language)

You should carefully consider your other options though; it is possible that a `while` or a `do` / `while` loop presents a more readable alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. However, I would suggest assigning start into a variable like `i` or something, because now you are changing the value of start as you iterate.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code as the following for the desired result:

```
while(start++<end){
    // your code
}
```

You get to take advantage of the fact that adding "++" after the variable name increments it after it is checked in the condition statement.